# How can I execute a commande on a remote server with ansible playbook with a user that cannot connect to the server

Tags: ssh, ansible

Her is my workflow.

> > ssh user1@remote-server
> >
> > su - user2
> >
> > somme commande only user2 can execute

user1 can not sudo user2 and user2 don't have ssh access.

I need to do this with ansible playbook and I can not change setting on the remote server.

Answer (score 0):

You can use for example the shell or command tasks but you'll also need the command `expect` because su requires interactive input of the password:

```
- name: Run a su user2 command
  shell: suCommand.sh
```

where suCommand.sh is:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect
spawn su -c ls user2
expect "Password: "
send -- "user2password\r"
interact
```